# Is it possible to derive the effective potential of a given theory by only using the RGE equations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, 1pi-effective-action

I know that it is possible to derive the RGE equations from the effective potential by requiring that the first derivative with respect to the renormalization scale $\mu$ vanishes:

$$ \dfrac{\mathrm{dV_{\mathrm{eff}}}}{\mathrm{d\mu}}  = 0.$$

Now I ask the reverse question: Is it possible to derive straightforwardly the effective potential from the $\beta$ functions of a given theory? How can I do it?

**Rmk:** I have in mind models with extended Higgs sectors.

Comment: If you only have a (first-order) differential equation, then will you not need some "initial/boundary condition" to fix a solution? Also, I don't see how this relates to extended Higgs sectors.

Comment: Doesn't RGE establish the scaling property of particular Green's function? In that sense we can only deduce how a particular $G$ changes under scaling, not deduce its internal properties which would require exact diagram by diagram calculations. That is say $G(k) = k^n f(k/\Lambda)$, then RGE tells us what $n$ is but doesn't tell us anything about the dimensionless function $f(x)$.